# Does joblib duplicate class instances passed as arguments to a function?

Tags: python, joblib

I am using joblib to run some simulations in parallel (for a MWE see my answer to this question). The simulator is a class instance which gets called at every step with an external action. If I am running 4 simulations, I want 4 different independent simulators. However, my call to joblib is something like this

```
simulator = Simulator(...)
results = Parallel(n_jobs=4)([delayed(run_simulation)(simulator) for i in range(4)])
```

The same `Simulator` instance is passed as argument in all cases. Is this instance duplicated before being given to the workers (which is what I want), or do they all use the same instance (which I do not want)?

I have answered my own question, although I am not sure of the answer. Any further insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This MWE of the problem described in the question appears to suggest that it does

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1

    def call(self, a):
        self.c += a

    def get(self):
        return self.c

a = A()

def call_a(inst):
    inst.call(1)
    return inst.get()

result = Parallel(n_jobs=4)([delayed(call_a)(a) for i in range(10)])
```

When you run it you obtain

```
In [2]: result
Out[2]: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

If the instance `a` was shared, you would have obtained the numbers from `2` to `11`.